# Why are there only two perturbation modes in the early Universe?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Cosmology textbooks and lecture notes often mention that there are two possible modes in the early Universe - adiabatic and isothermal, with the former affecting both the matter field and the radiation field, while the latter affecting only the matter field. However, these texts do not make it clear as to why there ought to be only two possible modes and why the solutions are either adiabatic and isothermal. I am looking for a more thorough explanation on this topic.